# Restore previous GCloud IAM policy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I accidentally replaced my current IAM Policy on a Google project (with GKE services) running the following python script:

```py
def set_policy(project_id, email):
    """Assign role to a service account."""

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        filename=os.getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'),
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        'cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    policy = service.projects().setIamPolicy(
        resource=project_id,
        body={
            'policy': {
                'version': 3,
                "bindings": [
                    {
                        "role": f"roles/storage.objectAdmin",
                        "members": [
                            f"serviceAccount:{email}"
                        ],
                        "condition": {
                            "title": "TenantSpace",
                            "expression": f'resource.type == "storage.googleapis.com/Object" && resource.name.startsWith("projects/{project_id}/buckets/demo/")',
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    ).execute()
    return policy
```

I didn't think that it would have replaced my whole policy since I was actually trying to add a role to an existing service account. I'm the owner so fortunately I could restore my previous user roles but I'm not sure if there was some other important roles for default Google service accounts. So my questions are:

1. This script should have changed only the roles inside this page right? https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam
2. Is there a way to view a history of recent activities involving IAM and therefore a way to restore a snapshot previous to this breaking change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to restore the previous roles by accessing the `serviceData` entry on the Logs Explorer. Running query with `resource.type="project"` and filtering the time range exactly to the period of interest, one can find the array of deleted bindings inside `serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas`.

The forward process was a bit tedious but I managed to restore the bindings to the correct snapshot.

[image: Logs Explorer]

Answer (score 2):

Is the project part of an Organization? If yes, authenticate as an ORG admin in the Google Cloud Console. You can then add users and service accounts back into IAM. Audit logging will tell you what was deleted.

If not, your code should have failed because the API does not allow removing the last owner of a project. If you are locked out of a standalone project, only Google Cloud support can help you restore access.

Note: SetIamPolicy overwrites the existing policy. The correct procedure is to read the existing policy, modify and then set it.

Comment: Thanks. I could log back to the organization project. I'm trying to look for IAM roles that have been deleted by mistake. Do you happen to know where to look exactly? Because I'm struggling to find out the specific data I need

Comment: You now have a challenge. Audit logging records activity. The key is processing that information. Did you open a support ticket?

Comment: Actually I managed to find out the exact serviceData I was looking for during the IAM policy replacement. That gave me the bindings list of each removed role. I just added manually the entries which was a bit tedious but it went well at the end. Thanks again for the support.

Comment: Where did you find the exact serviceData? Thank you for the update. Both of your questions on IAM will hopefully help future cloud admins.

Comment: Inside Logging > Logs Explorer . Running query with resource.type="project" and filtering the time range exactly to the period of interest I was able to inspect the log entry. Specifically inside "serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas".

Comment: But the details on IAM roles are not recorded in that entry for audit logging. Can you post a `redacted` example?

Comment: Just added an answer which is a bit more talkative.

Comment: Thank you. Your screenshot educated me - I did not see the roles in my previous testing.